# autoplay not working when using controlsList=""

Tags: html, html5-video

I want to hide the download option on the controls in the video tag but when I use `controlsList="nodownload"` It hides the download button from options but autoplay will stop working. I want autoplay to work and hide the download button. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls autoplay controlsList="nodownload"/>
```

Comment: What download button?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans if you go to the 3 dots on the controls and click it you will see download if you dont use ```controlsList="nodownload"```

Comment: This may just be me, but running your snippet just gives me a broken video element.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thats weird it's working on my side (on stack overflow snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `muted` attribute. Unfortunately, this is a browser implementation. `autoplay` and `muted` go hand-in-hand, see [video autoplay considered harmful](https://www.mux.com/blog/video-autoplay-considered-harmful)

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls autoplay muted controlsList="nodownload"/>
```

Comment: But I want the audio!!

Comment: https://www.mux.com/blog/video-autoplay-considered-harmful

Comment: hum thats seems to be the issue thanks for the blog post!

Comment: I know, it really sucks, if autoplay needs to be curtailed, it would've been better if the volume had a limit until the user adjusts the volume.

Comment: How does hulu/netflix get both audio and autoplay on load though?

Comment: the trick is that this only applies on autoplay _without user interaction_. Streaming services have a landing page where you need to do a thing (click a button, an element etc) and then you can start as many audio and video elements as you like. So really, you don't want autoplay: you want "video.play() when the user does literally anything that counts as a true interaction on my page". (and note that scrolling etc. don't count as page interactions)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah but to test that I wanted to autoplay the video if user realoads the page so I did ```$(window).on('load', function(){ $('video').trigger('play'); });``` but I get error ```DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.```

Comment: That's not a page interaction, so you don't get to do that. Your video could be extremely questionable content (fill in your favourite category of "if this started playing over my speakers I would probably get fired" here) so your page does not get to play video _until_ the user has done something that indicates that the page load was intentional, by interacting with the page. So, you can listen for document level mouse clicks/touch events, or certain key events, but you don't get to properly autoplay before then.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Now that's my question right there. I went to Hulu's website and played a video then paused it and reloaded the video page and on load, the video auto-played with audio. Where is the user interaction in that?

Comment: Don't know: I don't have hulu, but you do, so... fire up your dev tools and find out?

Comment: true :)) ..... @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans